# Lossless rate-limiting in RxJS with queue clearing

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

In rxjs5, I'm trying to implement a `Throttler` class.

```
import Rx from 'rxjs/rx';

export default class Throttler {
  constructor(interval) {
    this.timeouts = [];
    this.incomingActions = new Rx.Subject();
    this.incomingActions
      .concatMap(action => Rx.Observable.just(action).delay(interval / 2))
      .subscribe(action => action());
  }

  clear() {
    // How do I do this?
  }

  do(action) {
    this.incomingActions.next(action);
  }
}
```

The following invariants must hold:

- every action passed to `do` gets added to an action queue
- the action queue gets processed in order and at a fixed interval as determined by the constructor parameter
- the action queue can be cleared using `clear()`.

My current implementation, as seen above, handles the fixed interval, but I don't know how to clear the queue. It also has the problem that all actions are delayed by `interval / 2`ms even when the queue is empty.

P.S. The way I describe the invariants maps very easily to an implementation with setInterval and an array as a queue, but I'm wondering how I would do this with Rx.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like not a good place for the default `Subject` class. Extending it with your own subclass would be better because of reasons you listed.

However, in your case I'd try to identify each action that comes to `.do(action)` method with some index and add `.filter()` operator before `subscribe()` to be able to cancel particular actions by checking some array for what indices are marked as canceled. Since you're using `concatMap()` you know that actions will be always called in the order they were added. Then `clear()` method that you want would just mark all actions to be canceled in the array.

You can also add `.do()` operator after `concatMap()` and keep track of how many action are scheduled at the moment with some accumulator. Adding action would cause `scheduledAction++` while passing `.do()` right before `.subscribe()` would `scheduledAction--`. Then you can use this variable to decide whether you want to chain a new action with `.delay(interval / 2)` or not.